# Error de centrado con CSS

Tags: css

Mi clase `.contenido` no se centra, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Éste es mi código:

```
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.portada{
  padding: 5% 5% 0 5%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.Logotipo{
  width: 90%;
}

.contenido{
  text-align: center;
}
.texto{
  width: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.microfonos{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.microfono{
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 50px 50px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: .2s;
}
.microfono:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background: #F0F0F0;
}
.microfono a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.microfono p{
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.footer{
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 100px;
  padding: 50px 100px;
}
.footer ul{
  text-align: left;
}
.footer a{
  color: black;
}
.fondo{
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Vamos a necesitar algo más de contexto: ¿puedes incluir el HTML asociado? También, ¿a qué te refieres con que no se centra? ¿El elemento como tal o el texto dentro del elemento?

Comment: Con text-align: center; solo centraras tu texto. Si publicas tu código html podremos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías mostrarnos como esta el código html, un tip para centrar un div sería
.contenido{
margin-left:auto;
margin_right:auto;
}
o colocar el .contenido dentro de un div display:table; y al .contenido darle disaplay:table-cell,

otra recomendación bastante viable es comenzar a usar bootstrap ese framwork te quitará muchos dolores de cabeza